# SQL use REPLACE function to search through a table variable and update a field

Tags: sql

The problem I'm trying to solve is to use REPLACE function to look trough a list of values and make all of the various replacements, but the challenge is doing this on a different table. Basically, I'm looking for a smarter way than doing 25-100 nested REPLACE functions.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:
Variable table to hold the list of characters/string (Random length and mixed characters) I want to locate and replace later.

```
DECLARE @ReplaceList TABLE (String VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @ReplaceList (String)
VALUES ('AAA1 - '), ('AAB1 - '), ('A3 !'), ('BC4 - ')

String
AAA1 -   
AAB1 -   
A3 !  
BC4 -
```

Then I have a table (Jobs) with over a thousand rows with descriptions that need all of these replaced/deleted.

```
Title
AAA1 - Job 1  
AAA1 - Job 2  
A3 ! Job 4  
BC4 - Job 5
```

End Result Needed is:

```
Title
Job 1  
Job 2  
Job 4  
Job 5
```

The rough thought I had for the SQL code out line would be similar to

```
SELECT REPLACE(Jobs.Title,@ReplaceList.String,'')
FROM Jobs
```

I know this code is no where near what would actually work since it may need a sub-query or something, but I think it conveys the idea of using the data from a variable table as a master list of what to replace in each field of a different table.

Comment: Perhaps cross apply will help...

Comment: you want remove the string of the left of 'Job' ???  ... which db you are using ??

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add the one for the DBMS you are actually using.

Comment: The strings I'm Trying to replace/remove are not always on the left.

Comment: Since it's a work DB I can not post the actual data.

Comment: Over all I'm looking for a universal way to add strings into a table variable, and then have all instances of those string removed. There can be multiple  chunks that need to be removed in the same string as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t see a join combined with replace working. You will need to apply the `REPLACE` function once for each string--that is, row--to search-and-replace for, and each subsequent check will need to be fed the results of the prior one. So, iteration is required.

The following will do it. I built out your search table to allow for full string replacements—just set “ReplaceWith” to the empty string to blank out text. (Note that the order strings are searched for matters when you are replacing text with other text that may itself need to be replaced!)

This will not perform too well for big datasets, as you will need to go through the target table once for every search string, and you will update every row on each pass.

```
SET NOCOUNT on


--  Set up table of strings to search through
DECLARE @Jobs TABLE
 (Title  varchar(100)  not null)

INSERT @Jobs values
  ('AAA1 - Job 1, box  ')
 ,('AAA1 - Job 2, fox  ')
 ,('A3 ! Job 4  ')
 ,('BC4 - Job 5')
 ,('The quick red fox')

SELECT *
 from @Jobs


--  Set up table of search-and-replace strings
DECLARE @ReplaceList TABLE
 (
   LookFor       varchar(100)  not null
  ,ReplaceWith   varchar(100)  not null
  ,ReplaceOrder  int           not null  PRIMARY KEY
 )

INSERT @ReplaceList values
  ('AAA1 - ', 'AA1 - ', 1)
 ,('AAB1 - ', 'AB1 - ', 2)
 ,('A3 !', 'A3 - ', 3)
 ,('BC4 - ', 'XXX - ', 4)
 ,('fox', 'lox', 5)
 ,('  ', ' ', 6)

SELECT *
 from @ReplaceList



DECLARE
  @LoopCheck    int
 ,@NextToDo     int
 ,@ReplaceThis  varchar(100)
 ,@ReplaceWith  varchar(100)


SET @LoopCheck = 0


WHILE @LoopCheck is not null
 BEGIN
    --  Loop is processed once for every row in @ReplaceList

    SET @NextToDo = null

    --  Get the next replace string to check
    SELECT
      @NextToDo = min(ReplaceOrder)
     from @ReplaceList
     where ReplaceOrder > @LoopCheck


    IF @NextToDo is null
        --  No more to do, exit out
        BREAK


    --  Get the replacement strings
    SELECT
       @ReplaceThis = LookFor
      ,@ReplaceWith = ReplaceWith
     from @ReplaceList
     where ReplaceOrder = @NextToDo


    --  Update all target strings as necessary
    UPDATE @Jobs
     set Title = replace(Title, @ReplaceThis, @ReplaceWith)


    --  On to the next one
    SET @LoopCheck = @NextToDo
 END


--  Waddawe got?
SELECT *
 from @Jobs
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for in that it covers all the other cases that come up in my larger actual DB. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had a follow up question to this, How would the code change if I wanted to make this act more like a function for one field being selected. For example, rather than creating a whole new variable table that I'm joining. I would like my to make it like a function (let's call it CustomReplace) that I could use in a select statement.            Select CustomeReplace(Title) From @Jobs.   This way it looks at one value and runs through the 'at'Replace list table, without creating a whole separate table that needs to be joined back in.

Comment: I'd take the code above and modify it to fit in a multi-statement function call (check out `CREATE FUNCTION`) with the sole parameter being the value to modify. Note, however, that this kind of function can seriously degrade performance if nested within a larger query.

Comment: Can you provide a link or example of how to create such a multi-statement function? Also, is there such thing as a temporary function? I have read only access so I can't create function directly in the Database, or if the function could be stored in a local database and reference that would work too.      I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: SQL Server Books Online is your go-to place. Here's the entry for the syntax for and example of `CREATE FUNCTION`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql

Comment: You cannot create a true temporary function (e.g. #MyFunc), but you should be able to create a function in tempdb, and then reference it from elsewhere (e.g. `PRINT tempdb.dbo.MuFunc()`)

Answer (score 0):

In mysql this will help you.

```
select replace(j.Title,rl.string, '') from ReplaceList rl ,  job j where j.Title like concat('%',rl.string_,'%');
```

Comment: This was very helpful, but I realized that there was a small over sight when I simplified the example. There may need to be multiple things in the list that need to be replaced in a single string.  For example, a value could be 'AAAA - Job 1 A3 ! - ', so there are two replaces that need to happen in the same string.            How can I replace all of the items from the @ReplaceList rather than stopping after the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Title table can be formatted with some consistency:

```
Create table #ReplaceList (String VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #ReplaceList (String)
VALUES ('AAA1 - '), ('AAB1 - '), ('A3 ! - '), ('BC4  - ')

Select * from #ReplaceList;

Create table #Title (mytitle varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Title values ('AAA1 - Job 1'), ('AAA1 - Job 2'), ('A3 ! - Job 4'), ('BC4  - Job 5')

Select * from #Title

create table #string_job (string varchar(100), job varchar(50))
insert into #string_job 
select left(mytitle, 7) as string,
       right(mytitle, 5) as job
from #title

select string, job from #string_job

select J.job as 'Title'
from #string_job J
right join #ReplaceList R
on R.string = J.string
```

Comment: The issue is that there is no consistency in the title format. I basically just need a list of strings that can all be pulled out no matter where in the Title string they show up. So Left() and Right() don't work in my actual case.